# Meaning of "Top Bank of a channel"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading an article about Design of elevated flumes (flume is a human-made channel for water). Here is a part of the article,

> 8.1 Data Requirement
>
> Elevations:
>
> - Top Bank, TB
> - Water Surface, WS
> - Canal Bed, CB

My question is, what does Elevation of Top Bank mean? I looked up at [OALD dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bank_1?q=bank) and I think bank refers to sense 5 "the side of a river, canal, etc. and the land near it". But still not sure about the meaning of the phrase. Does that mean elevation from top of a side of flume to the ground?

Comment: So, flumes are associated with channels or canals, yes. So, bank does mean the sides of a canal or channel. I assume top bank means the distance from the water surface to the top of the bank [of the canal or channel], in which the flume flows. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Given the other heights you mention I agree with @Lambie it is almost certainly the very top of the bank of the flume.

Comment: Agreed with Lambie and mdewey above on what it *likely* means, but if this is technical jargon, then only an expert can definitively answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help? Google is your friend.

[image]

Comment: What a great find!